# 404 error on default post type and default taxonomy fronted page

Tags: posts, pages, taxonomy, 404-error, front-end

I have installed WordPress through Softaculus installer. After that I logged in and created a post. when I wanted to view the post it says 404 page not found.
[image: Post type and Taxonomy pages are showing this]

It works fine when permalinks are set to numeric. But other than numeric shows this message. 
Additionally: I am using Cloudflare's CDN
[image: Cloudfare CDN Status]
I don't think cloudfare is generating such problem. But still, I provided it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Softaculus created the problem.